# Prevent svg translation of fontawesome

Tags: angular, svg, font-awesome-5

I have en issue with angular and font awesome. On first generation of list of icons suddenly all css class based icons are translated to svg. It affects only solid icons. for example :

```
<i class="fas fa-2x fa-minus-square"></i>
```

is translated somehow to

```
<svg _ngcontent-c16="" class="svg-inline--fa fa-minus-square fa-w-14 fa-2x"
 ng-reflect-ng-class="fas fa-2x fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="minus-square"
 role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
    <path fill="currentColor"
      d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM92 296c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-56c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h264c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v56c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H92z">
    </path>
</svg>
<!-- <i _ngcontent-c16="" class="fas fa-2x fa-minus-square" ng-reflect-ng-class="fas fa-2x fa-minus-square"></i> -->
```

Is there any option which can prevent this situation? Force somehow translation?

It can be problematic. For example I cannot use solid icons :(

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you'd like Font Awesome not to automatically replace `<i>` tags that look like icons with the corresponding `<svg>`s, you could [change the configuration](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/font-awesome-api) to disable `autoReplaceSvg`.

If you're loading via `<script>` tag, that might look like this (make sure to do the config *before* loading Font Awesome):

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Notice how this gets configured before we load Font Awesome
      window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: false }
    </script>
    <script src="fontawesome.js"></script>
    <script src="fa-solid.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Or if you're building your own bundle and can access the config from within your own script you could do this:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'

fontawesome.config = { autoReplaceSvg: false }
```

Comment: How can you manually replace SVG though? I haven't been able to find anything in the docs...

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue, the  icon tag was actually translated to SVG when I inspected the element.

The problem was I was loading fontawesome both via CSS and JS calls. When I removed the call to the JS lib and only called the CSS file, the icons rendered properly.

Comment: Same for me. Removing the JS file import fixed this issue and also another issue where toggling between solid and regular icons in a Vue.js application did not work.

Comment: Thank you guys. It helped me too.

Comment: I cannot tell you guys how much this comment helped me !!! I was stuck on something for over 2 days, not directly related to Font awesome but it turns out the issue was because of font awesome loaded css and js

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't prevent translation to SVG. Nest SVG inside the `<i>` element. It worked for me to keep CSS.

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";

FontAwesome.config.autoReplaceSvg = "nest"
```

Here is the updated documentation for [Font Awesome 6](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/apis/javascript/configuration#autoreplacesvg-through-nesting)