# Icon format appears as svg in source code

Tags: html

I'm using font-awesome 4 in my project.
I have a problem with fontawesome4 icons and I don't have any idea what causes this issue. So, my icons appears as SVG element in source codes:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983637/prevent-svg-translation-of-fontawesome

Comment: For future reference, please do not post links to code/images, but rather include them inline in the question.   People are not very likely to follow links.