# fa icons are replaced by svg in laravel and vue js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.5 and vue js 2.5.7. I use fa icons in my project. but i include app.js in my code all fa icons arecommented and svg are included and ! and ? are showing. how to prevent this ? Also  `fontawesome-i2svg-active fontawesome-i2svg-complete` these classes are added in html tag automatically

i am using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` for including fa icons

`<i class="fa fa-trash delete_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>` this is the fa icon i used. but this is not inside the vue element.

Comment: Please go to page source and check this CDN link is working or not in your end.

Comment: Its working. if i remove app.js from scripts then it works fine

Comment: This link might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983637/prevent-svg-translation-of-fontawesome . It is an Angular post, but the way to solve the problem is generic.