# Font Awesome in React app Svg translation

Tags: reactjs, icons, font-awesome

In react app i have working font awesome icons. For some reason font-awesome started to translate icons to svg. I am using css aproach.

[image: svg translation]

But fontawesome translates all icons that I have into svg as can be seen in screenshot above. I want to turn it off somehow.

I have gone through docs and found there is config to use.
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/setup/configuration

Can  it can be turned off (with config) in main app launcher like this?

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'

const App = () => {

fontawesome.config = { autoReplaceSvg: false }
...
return (
<>
 <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
....
</ThemeProvider>
</>
)
...
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide us with more detail?

Comment: You can find out your answer from here. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301152](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301152)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem can be solved by using css version instead of js.